# What book do these notes synopsize?

Tags: tefilla, jewish-books

I picked up a (IIRC ArtScroll) *sidur* (prayer book) in my synagogue one day. It had no indication of ownership in it, but it had some handwritten notes (all in the same hand). Among them were:

- Between the blessing "גאל ישראל" and the blessing "השכיבנו" during weekday *maariv*: "normally, Shimona Esrei should immediately follow גאל, but see vol 10, ¶ 97"
- On the words "כנגד כלם" in the passage after the morning blessings on the *Tora*: "study of Torah = all the mitzvahs above vol 7 p 205"

What multi-volume book is referred to here?

Comment: what nussach was the sidur?

Comment: When, where and by whom was the Siddur published? (This could help us think of relevant books.)

Comment: @Menachem, DoubleAA, if I recall correctly, the _sidur_ was an ArtScroll _sidur_, though I don't remember more detail than that. I don't see that adding that information to the question will help me get any answers: the citations, after all, are clearly not to the _sidur_ itself.

Comment: @msh210, yes but depending on the Nussach, we could guess which books the owner might be citing. If it was a Siddur Yechaveh Da'at, I might suspect Yalkut Yosef. If it was a Roedelheim, I wouldn't, and so on.

Comment: @Yitzchak Or if it was Sefard we could expect Hasidic sources.

Comment: The first thing that comes to mind is the Zohar.